# batch file that joins 2 files with others in a sudirectory

Tags: append, text-files, batch-processing

In a directory I have 2 files: content1.txt and content2.txt

I also have 2 sub-directories in the directory: input and output

The 'input' sub-directory contains a number of text files.

The 'output' sub-directory is empty.

What I wish for is a batch file that will take each file from the 'input' sub-directory, one at a time, then create a new file containing content1.txt + inputfile#1 + content2.txt, and place that  new file in the 'output' sub-directory, and name it the same as inputfile#1, then create a new file containing content1.txt + inputfile#2 + content2.txt, and place that  new file in the 'output' sub-directory, and name it the same as inputfile#2, then do the same for inputfile#3, etc. etc., and halt when the last file in the 'input' sub-directory has been processed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Or if that is too difficult to do, an alternative would be to have everything in the same directory, with an additional textfile 'filelist.txt' that lists the names of each file to be added to content1.txt and content2.txt, one file-name per line.